# R - How do I use selectInput in shiny to change the x and fill variables in a ggplot renderPlot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to make an interactive shiny dashboard that has an interactive plot where you can change the values of the plot. The code chunk that I'm putting inside of renderPlot works normally, so I don't understand why count isn't showing on the y axis when I use selectInput to change the X and Fill variables.

```
 inputPanel(
  selectInput('x', 'X', names(data)),
  selectInput('y', 'Y', names(data))
)

renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(x = input$x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = input$y), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
 coord_flip() + 
 theme(legend.position = "top")
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the `input$x` and `input$y` are `character` class.  So, instead of `aes`, use `aes_string`

```
renderPlot({
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = input$x)) +
  geom_bar(aes_string(fill = input$y), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
})
```

---

A reproducible example with `data(mpg)`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


data(mpg)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    selectInput('x', 'X', choices = c("manufacturer", "model", "year", "cyl", "class"),
          selected = "class"),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', choices = c( "trans", "fl", "drv"), 
  selected = "drv")
  ),

  mainPanel(plotOutput("outplot"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$outplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mpg, aes_string(x = input$x)) +
      geom_bar(aes_string(fill= input$y), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
      coord_flip() + 
      theme(legend.position = "top")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I was stuck for hours ;-;

Comment: Do you know how to make the selectinput be factor levels of the columns, instead of just columns?

Comment: @ThomasKidd  In that case you may have to use `levels(data[,col])`.  Not clear about the question though.  Can u post a new question

Comment: @akrun If this would be used for multiple plots, is there an incentive to have the inout for the the column selection assigned to a global `reactiveVal`? E.g. `globalXY <- reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)` with `observe` to update the values?