# How to fill in the variables into the stat_funciton() programmatically?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I saw the answer to the question to "filling in the variables into ggplot": [R - How do I use selectInput in shiny to change the x and fill variables in a ggplot renderPlot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473915/r-how-do-i-use-selectinput-in-shiny-to-change-the-x-and-fill-variables-in-a-gg)

How can I do similar things to stat_function?

Here's my code in side the renderPlot:

```
ggplot(data = removedNA,mapping = aes_string(x = input$x)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +    
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 40000, args = list(mean = mean(input$x, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sqrt(var(input$x,na.rm = TRUE)))) +
  labs(title = input$x)
```

I got the histogram and a Warning:
`Warning in mean.default(input$x, na.rm = TRUE) :   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `input$x` is a character and hence `mean(input$x, na.rm = TRUE)`will not work. Instead you could do `mean(removeNA[[input$x]], na.rm = TRUE)`.

A minimal reprex using `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

removeNA <- mtcars

input <- list(
  x = "mpg"
)

mean_x <- mean(removeNA[[input$x]], na.rm = TRUE)
sd_x <- sqrt(var(removeNA[[input$x]],na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(data = removeNA, mapping = aes_string(x = input$x)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) +    
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 40000, args = list(mean = mean_x, sd = sd_x)) +
  labs(title = input$x) 
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]